# convert array to string php

Tags: php, arrays, implode

I have array like this

```
$test=Array ( [0] => en [1] => fr )
```

when I use this command

```
$a=implode(",",$test);
print_r($a);
```

result is:

> en,fr

but I want this result

> 'en','fr'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

change like this

```
$a="'".implode("','",$test)."'";
```

Check your output : https://eval.in/587278

Comment: The question reveals tremendoul lazyness, but that is the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

This could be an option:

```
$a = implode(",", array_map(function($el) {return "'" . $el . "'";}, $test));
```

This approach focuses on readability and generality. You could have another transformation for each array element, using an anonymous function, before imploding.